# wp_logout_url($uri) having two redirect values

Tags: logout

```
$uri= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

`wp_logout_url($uri)` having two redirect values like this

```
http://localhost/sarkari/wp-login.php?action=logout&redirect_to=%2Fsarkari%2F&_wpnonce=b5e3b954df&redirect_to=http://localhost/sarkari/2017/06/01/new-sample-post/
```

but i want only first one redirect_to value and remove or trim the another redirect_to value.

i want this `http://localhost/sarkari/wp-login.php?action=logout&redirect_to=%2Fsarkari%2F&_wpnonce=b5e3b954df`

Comment: If you want to remove part of URL... just remove part of URL? I am not quite following what is _causing_ it to have to redirects, maybe you could elaborate a bit on the context.

Comment: can't remove the URL

Comment: Do you have any plugins installed? The default behavior of `wp_logout_url()` is to use `add_query_arg()` which will correctly modify a query arg rather than append it, unless some other plugin (or possibly theme function) is modifying it incorrectly, possibly via the `logout_url` filter.